# How to make these 2 figures be in subsequent pages (twosided document class)

Tags: graphics, figure-placement

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Chapters/Pictures/c_4/842/t x p, ts.png}
        \caption{Ring 842: Rock. Observations are highly variable for both parameters.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{\fill}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Chapters/Pictures/c_4/598/t x p, ts.png}
        \caption{Ring 598: Rock-like mixed. The red circle indicates a sample region where parameters follow the same patterns.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Time series plots relating Penetration and Torque Screw for rock.}
    \end{figure}
   
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Chapters/Pictures/c_4/557/t x p, ts.png}
        \caption{Ring 557: Soil. Parameters can be seen to overlap as indicated by Arrow 1 and throughout the ring. Arrow 2 shows a region where there is significant changes between parameters before overlapping again.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{\fill}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Chapters/Pictures/c_4/613/t x p, ts.png}
        \caption{Ring 613: Soil-like mixed. Throughout the ring, the parameters are strongly correlated and follow an overlapping distribution.}
    \end{subfigure}
    
    \caption{Time series plots relating Penetration and Torque Screw for soil.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your figures (which reproduce your problem), which we can compile as it is.

Comment: How tall are the figures?  Is there a reason you need to have them in `{figure}` environments?  (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/107497).  And mostly off topic: are you filenames really "t x p, ts.png"?  Spaces and especially commas seem to be asking for trouble.